Reduction of memory consumption in C++
I am writing a header file on C++ that implements interaction with quaternion. Quaternion can be interpreted as a + bi + cj + dk, so its components are stored in m_value in b, c, d, a order. I also support representing a quaternion as a scalar & vector. I've noticed that in method updateComponents()  I use 2x more memory than I actually need. How can I fix that? m_value and scalar & vector representation are required.
#ifndef QUAT_HPP
#define QUAT_HPP

#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
struct matrix_t {
    T data[16];
};

template<typename T>
struct vector3_t {
    T x, y, z;
};

template<typename T>
class Quat {
public:
    Quat() : scalar(0), vector{0, 0, 0} {
        updateComponents();
    }

    Quat(T a, T b, T c, T d) : scalar(a), vector{b, c, d} {
        updateComponents();
    }

    Quat(T angle, bool mode, vector3_t<T> axes) {
        if (!mode) {
            angle = angle * M_PI / 180;
        }
        T norm = std::sqrt(axes.x * axes.x + axes.y * axes.y + axes.z * axes.z);
        scalar = std::cos(angle / 2);
        vector.x = axes.x / norm * std::sin(angle / 2);
        vector.y = axes.y / norm * std::sin(angle / 2);
        vector.z = axes.z / norm * std::sin(angle / 2);
        updateComponents();
    }

    const T *data() const { return m_value; };

    Quat<T> operator+(const Quat<T> &q2) const {
        return Quat(scalar + q2.scalar, vector.x + q2.vector.x, vector.y + q2.vector.y, vector.z + q2.vector.z);
    }

    Quat<T> &operator+=(const Quat<T> &q2) {
        *this = *this + q2;
        updateComponents();
        return *this;
    }

    Quat<T> operator-(Quat q2) const {
        return Quat(scalar - q2.scalar, vector.x - q2.vector.x, vector.y - q2.vector.y, vector.z - q2.vector.z);
    }

    Quat<T> &operator-=(Quat q2) {
        *this = *this - q2;
        updateComponents();
        return *this;
    }

    Quat<T> operator*(Quat q2) const {
        T a1 = scalar, b1 = vector.x, c1 = vector.y, d1 = vector.z;
        T a2 = q2.scalar, b2 = q2.vector.x, c2 = q2.vector.y, d2 = q2.vector.z;
        return Quat(
                a1 * a2 - b1 * b2 - c1 * c2 - d1 * d2,
                a1 * b2 + a2 * b1 + c1 * d2 - c2 * d1,
                a1 * c2 + a2 * c1 + d1 * b2 - d2 * b1,
                a1 * d2 + a2 * d1 + b1 * c2 - b2 * c1);
    }

    Quat<T> operator*(T s) const { return Quat(scalar * s, vector.x * s, vector.y * s, vector.z * s); }

    Quat<T> operator*(vector3_t<T> vec) const {
        Quat<T> q2 = Quat(0, vec.x, vec.y, vec.z);
        return *this * q2;
    }

    Quat<T> operator~() const { return Quat(scalar, -vector.x, -vector.y, -vector.z); }

    bool operator==(Quat q2) const {
        return (scalar == q2.scalar && vector.x == q2.vector.x && vector.y == q2.vector.y && vector.z == q2.vector.z);
    }

    bool operator!=(Quat q2) const { return !(*this == q2); }

    explicit operator T() const {
        return std::sqrt(scalar * scalar + vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y + vector.z * vector.z);
    }

    matrix_t<T> rotation_matrix() const {
        Quat<T> q = normalize();
        T s = q.scalar, x = q.vector.x, y = q.vector.y, z = q.vector.z;
        T r_11 = 1 - 2 * y * y - 2 * z * z, r_12 = 2 * x * y - 2 * z * s, r_13 = 2 * x * z + 2 * y * s,
          r_21 = 2 * x * y + 2 * z * s, r_22 = 1 - 2 * x * x - 2 * z * z, r_23 = 2 * y * z - 2 * x * s,
          r_31 = 2 * x * z - 2 * y * s, r_32 = 2 * y * z + 2 * x * s, r_33 = 1 - 2 * x * x - 2 * y * y;
        return {r_11, r_21, r_31, 0, r_12, r_22, r_32, 0, r_13, r_23, r_33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    }

    matrix_t<T> matrix() const {
        return {scalar, -vector.x, -vector.y, -vector.z, vector.x, scalar, -vector.z, vector.y,
                vector.y, vector.z, scalar, -vector.x, vector.z, -vector.y, vector.x, scalar};
    }

    T angle(bool mode = true) const { return mode ? 2 * std::acos(scalar) : 2 * std::acos(scalar) * 180 / M_PI; }

    vector3_t<T> apply(vector3_t<T> vec) const {
        Quat<T> q = normalize();
        Quat<T> qv = q * vec;
        Quat<T> qq = qv * (~q);
        return {qq.vector.x, qq.vector.y, qq.vector.z};
    }

private:
    T m_value[4];
    T scalar;
    vector3_t<T> vector;

    void updateComponents() {
        m_value[3] = scalar;
        m_value[0] = vector.x;
        m_value[1] = vector.y;
        m_value[2] = vector.z;
    }

    Quat<T> normalize() const {
        T norm = T(*this);
        return *this * (1 / norm);
    }
};
#endif


I've read about union, but I think it won't be as memory efficient as I expect.

what are the allowable values for T ?!

How is the code you've shown being used?  (e.g.  what are the needs of the program that uses your class) How have you determined what "memory you need"?   And how have you determined the amount of memory your program actually uses?       There is much more to calculating memory usage than just adding up the memory your program allocates, or the data structures you use.   Memory is also needed to represent the program itself (instructions, etc) - the amount of overhead for that depends on your host system, operating system,  instruction set architecture, etc etc.

I use 2x more memory than I actually need. -- How did you determine this?  Did you look at the generated assembly code for an optimized version of your C++ code?

Why do you even have T m_value[4];?

Quat(T angle, bool mode, vector3_t<T> axes) -- Why did you not focus on this being inefficient or consuming memory?  The axes is passed by-value, meaning a complete temporary copy of axes is created.  The same thing here: Quat<T> operator-(Quat q2) and in other function calls.  You should be passing by const reference, not by value.

@AhmedAEK float and double

You are storing the data twice, once as 4 elements and another time as a scalar+vector. Pick one representation to cut down on object size.

seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/702679/15649230

@PaulMcKenzie thank you for this remark, I've fixed that

@NathanOliver it is required by tech task. In method *data() I need to return pointer to 4 quaternion components

@John Then that is the only member you should have.

@NathanOliver I've already thought about that, but the task is: "Note that a quaternion can be represented as a combination of a scalar and a vector of three components. Accordingly, quaternion and scalar/vector operations should be viewed from this perspective", so I'm a little bit confused

Your array of 4 members still qualifies as that.  How its implemented internally doesn't really matter accept for hard requirements like having a data function.  Because you have that then you need the array storage.  What you can do though is make references to those array elements and name them the scalar and vector names in your functions so that it more natural to use since you are "using" a scalar and vector instead of a raw array when writing all of your functions.

There's one implementation under boost. It also provide s an octornion class.

@John -- float and double -- FYI, your program compiles if T is std::string, but dies when it is run.  See this.  You need to implement compile-time checking for numeric types to avoid the error.

If you need *data() to return what it is you have 2 options.  Use m_value for everything, it wouldn't look quite as nice using [0] instead of .x ect but it would do what you want it to do and otherwise the code would function identically.
Or, you could get into the weeds of manual memory management by newing and assigning an array that would have been m_value with every *data() call.  This would have the potential to very quickly use alot more memory than what you have now if you weren't careful with it but it does have the advantage of not letting other code mess with your private member as it can now
